# Why Xcode doesn't show descriptions in "Quick Help"?

Tags: xcode, xcode9

I'm working on a project and suddenly Xcode (Version 9.1 (9B55)) stopped showing the descriptions of classes, methods etc. in a Quick Help. I can see the same behaviour when I option-click on the classes and methods. Here how it looks, for example, when I tap on a `viewDidLoad()` method:

[image: No description in Quick Help]

However, when I open another project, it works fine. Here is a screenshot from another project, when I tap on a `viewDidLoad()` method:

[image: There is a description in a Quick Help]

So, I think, this isn't an issue related to Xcode itself (or I'm wrong), but maybe I have accidentally broken something in my project. Anyway, I can't figure out what can cause this issue. Do you have any ideas?